# How to improve function TypeScript using generic types?

Tags: typescript

There are some similar parts in my code:

```
  for (let j = 0; j < this.homeworkList.length; j++) {
    this.homeworkList[
      j
    ].subjectName = LocalService.getDictionaryEntryStatic(
      this.homeworkList[j].subjectId
    );
  }
```

Or this:

```
  for (let j = 0; j < this.data.length; j++) {
    this.data[
      j
    ].name = LocalService.getDictionaryEntryStatic(
      this.data[j].id
    );
  }
```

As you can see both codes change array and set new property by value from `LocalService.getDictionaryEntryStatic()`.

I can apply generic type for this function.

```
  function mapObject<T>(data: T, key: string, newPropertyName:string) {
        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
               data[i][newPropertyName] = LocalService.getDictionaryEntryStatic(data[i][key]);
        }
    }
```

Do you have any recommendations how to improve this function?

Comment: Where do you use `U`?

Comment: It was removed, updated

Comment: Your data is `T[]`, not `T`.

Comment: what is the signature of `getDictionaryEntryStatic`, can it map any type of value or just `strings` ? Does `newPropertyName` need to already be in the object or can it be an added property ? There is a more type-safe version of this but is depends on those answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ensure that the key is an actual property of your data items:

```
function mapObject<T extends object, U extends keyof T>(
    list: T[], key: U, newPropertyName: string
) {
    for (const item of list) {
        item[newPropertyName] = LocalService.getDictionaryEntryStatic(item[key]);
    }
}
```

… Or just not use generics at all:

```
function mapObject(list: object[], key: string, newPropertyName:string) {
    for (const item of list) {
        item[newPropertyName] = LocalService.getDictionaryEntryStatic(item[key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is actually not that much point of using generics here. You can simply use

```
function mapObject(data: Array<any>, key: string, newPropertyName: string)
```

Or if you want to use generics, then something like this

```
function mapObject<T extends Array<U>, U extends { [index: string]: any }>(data: T, key: string, newPropertyName: string)
```